# What kinds of controllers should I consider for extensibility in ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` for the UI and `System.Web.Http.ApiController` for the API in prototyping a web interface for large ERP application. I have figured out a way to make the UI somewhat extensible with the question [Deploying un-compiled ASP.NET MVC Razor application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982206/deploying-un-compiled-asp-net-mvc-razor-application/20996354). Now I am wondering, due to the strict nature of `ApiController` if there is some other class I should be considering for providing an open-ended interface for defining custom API transactions. Or is there some way to use `ApiController` in a more open-ended way where parameter count and type may be varied... perhaps by accepting an object parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an ASP.NET web application extensible is very straightforward because ASP.NET searches the bin directory for controller classes in *all* assemblies there. So if the party providing customizations can simply compile their code into a DLL and drop it into the bin directory, your web application will pick up all their controllers as well as the controllers from the standard delivery. As an example, I created the following class in a standalone DLL that referenced `System.Web.Http` and `System.Web.Mvc`:

```
Public Class CustomTestController
   Inherits ApiController

   Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
      Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
   End Function

End Class
```

I simply compiled it and copied it to the bin directory of the location where my web application was deployed, and then I could access `http://localhost/MyApplication/api/CustomTest/` and get back `value1` and `value2` in the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

For Web API, you could try implementing a custom action selector using [IHttpActionSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.ihttpactionselector%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) interface:

```
public class CustomActionSelector : IHttpActionSelector
{
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext context)
    {
        var method = GetMethod(context);
        return new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(GetController(method), method);
    }

    private MethodInfo GetMethod(HttpControllerContext context)
    {
        // Locate the target method using the extensibility framework of your choice 
        // (for example, MEF, pure reflection, etc.)
    }    

    private HttpControllerDescriptor GetController(MethodInfo method)
    {
        return new HttpControllerDescriptor() 
        {
            ControllerName = method.DeclaringType.Name, 
            ControllerType = method.DeclaringType
        };
    }
}
```

To register your new action selector place the following in your `global.asax` file under `Application_Start`:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new CustomActionSelector());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad that HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute is not in MVC4; it would have allowed me to specify an IHttpActionSelector only for one ApiController. Is there still any way to target 1 ApiController with the custom action selector?

Comment: Right now, my controller class is selected by a routing defined in `WebApiConfig`. Does that mean my controller class (if it relies on that routing) has to be derived from `ApiController`. If I want to consider another kind of controller, would I have to also implement `IHttpControllerSelector`?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN 1) I don't think it's possible 2) I'd say, you'd need something derived from `ApiController` (haven't tried not deriving, but I'd assume the framework casts the type internally to set the `ControllerContext` and other stuff).